# How to get last day data of previous 12 months from current month

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g

There is a table in oracle named emp_table with emp_name(name of employees), emp_att (values are P or A only), and date (in timestamp). I want to view emp_att values for last day(end date of months) of previous 12 months from current month. Please share a proper query to get that.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: It is self sufficient to explain the issue..Pls understand that everyone is not able to share screenshot of something which his/her company don't allow. You must think over it before de-rating the question.

Comment: I specifically did not request a screenshot. And I never asked to reveal confidential information. But a good question should contain some sample data (even if made up) and the result you want to see. Look at Littlefoot's answer - he actually had to invent the sample data himself. **You** should have provided something like that in your question. You might want to read [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/) for an introduction on how to ask a good question regarding SQL

Comment: I appreciate little foot's work.You must see that i have mentioned in brackets about the data each column contains and mallikarjuna replied with really a good approach. Little foot has shown a good explanatory approach. Short and precise question is better than long one. However thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that last date in your case may not be the last date of the month, and last date is same for all the employees for all the months:

```
SELECT  *  FROM 
(SELECT A.*,
LAST_VALUE(EMP_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(EMP_DATE,'MON-YYYY') ORDER BY TO_CHAR(EMP_DATE,'MON-YYYY')) LAST_DT
FROM EMP_DATE A
WHERE 
EMP_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'), -12) AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
WHERE EMP_DATE=LAST_DT
```

- the last_value function will give last working date 
  for particular month
- where condition in select statement will restrict dates to last one year from present date you can change sysdate with your own date

Comment: After FROM there should be the table name. Testing your suggestion.

Comment: don't have to give table name since it is inline view takes every thing from inside query

Comment: Everything worked fine with this query except one thing. With previous months last day data, it should show sysdate data, but it is showing data for one day before sysdate, i.e., it is showing data for 14th august if today is 15th august. After showing 31st July data if it will show today's data then it will be more fruitful.However thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Hi Shekar, it all depends on the data in the table, if you got today's data ie 16-AUG -2019 today itself you can see  today's date, it will go by the last date of particular month in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with emp_table (emp_name, emp_att, cdate) as
  2    (select 'Scott', 'P', date '2019-03-31' from dual union all
  3     select 'Scott', 'A', date '2019-04-30' from dual union all
  4     select 'Scott', 'A', date '2019-05-18' from dual union all  --> not the last day in May
  5     select 'Scott', 'P', date '2019-05-31' from dual union all
  6     select 'Scott', 'A', date '2019-06-13' from dual            --> not the last day in June
  7    )
  8  select emp_name, emp_att, cdate
  9  from emp_table
 10  where cdate >= add_months(sysdate, -12)
 11    and cdate = last_day(cdate);

EMP_N E CDATE
----- - ----------
Scott P 31.03.2019
Scott A 30.04.2019
Scott P 31.05.2019

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.will revert once checked.